# Фальсифицирование или фальсификация?

Tags: семантика

1. *Прокурор был обвинён в **фальсифицировании** улик по уголовному делу.*
2. *Прокурор был обвинён в **фальсификации** улик по уголовному делу.*

Есть ли смысловая разница между первым и вторым предложением? Какое из двух этих слов корректнее здесь употребить?

Comment: Вы правы, Aer. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прокурор был обвинён **в  фальсификации** улик по уголовному делу. Этот вариант **чаще встречается, но второй вариант также верен.**

**ФАЛЬСИФИЦИРОВАТЬ,** св. и нсв. что. Подделать - подделывать, исказить - искажать или подменить - подменять с целью выдать за подлинное, настоящее.Ф. материалы следствия. страд. Фальсификация (см.). Фальсифицирование,

**ФАЛЬСИФИКАЦИЯ,** **-1. к Фальсифицировать.** Разоблачить фальсификацию. Ф. документов. Ф. идеи. Это всё сплошная ф. Ф. исторических фактов. Ф. научных данных. Пресечь попытки фальсификации.  **2. Подделанная вещь,** выдаваемая за настоящую; подделка. Это настоящий рубин? - Нет, ф.

Таким образом, **фальсификация** - это и процесс фальсификации, и подделанная вещь, а **фальсифицирование** - это только процесс, при этом  частотность слова "фальсификация" в первом значении выше, чем у "фальсифицирования". Но иногда эти слова **используются как синонимы**.

Пример из одного текста:

Прокурор НЦБК обвинен **в фальсификации** дела Викола. Прокурора Адриана Попенко из национального центра по борьбе с коррупцией обвинили в **фальсифицировании** заказных дел.

Answer (score 1):

Да, разница есть:

Фальсифика́ция, ж.

1. Подделывание, изменение вида или свойства чего-л. с корыстной целью, чтобы выдать изделие за что-л. другое.
2. Подмена чего-л. подлинного, настоящего ложным, мнимым.
3. То, что выдается за настоящее; подделка.

Фальсифици́рование, ср.

1. Процесс действия по значению несовершенного глагола: фальсифицировать.

**Корректнее - *фальсификация*.**

Answer (score 1):

> 1. *Прокурор был обвинён **в фальсифицировании** улик по уголовному делу.*
> 2. *Прокурор был обвинён **в фальсификации** улик по уголовному делу.*
>
> Есть ли смысловая разница между первым и вторым предложением?

Смысловой разницы нет.

> Какое из двух этих слов корректнее здесь употребить?

Чаще используется (и потому корректнее)  — ***в фальсификации...***